# Is it possible to use Model without Migration in Lumen?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm currently migrating and rebuilding an ASP + SQL Server project to Lumen + Angularjs, which requires working with the existing database.

As I didn't find an easy way to create Migrations from an existing database in Lumen, I wonder if it's possible to work with Models without creating any Migration files. If yes, would there be any barriers working this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

Just fill `$table`, `$fillable`, `$connection` and `$primaryKey`  in your model and it would be fine. There won't be barriers